# Should I create a subdomain for webkiosk

Tags: asp.net, iis, architecture, software-design

Imagine there is a website for a restaurant called x.com and we have designed a webkiosk for x.com, too. how would you structure site content on IIS, and what are the best practices.
for example :
whould you put webkiosk inside x.com as a subfolder called kiosk and access it at x.com/kiosk or whould you make a subdomain called kiosk.x.com that points at kiosk subfolder ? or something else that is considered a best practice for this scenario. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to provide more info for a more specific answer, but hopefully this will help.  BTW I used to develop on IIS eons ago, so my IIS knowledge is way out of date.

**Short answer / TLDR**: use a subdomain, as it's simply more flexible in the long run.

Key considerations are: system change, security and who has system access.

**System change**

Assuming that the website and kiosk are functionally different, e.g. it's highly likely you'd want to change one but not the other (functional change, bug fix, etc).  The more closely tied they are the harder it will be to change one without affecting the other (think application pool restarts, etc).

Are you familiar with the [Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)?
It's an Object Orientated design principle but its very applicable across way more than just OO.

Another change consideration is what happens when you need to split up the hosting of the kiosk and the website?  Let's say you decide you need to run the kiosk on totally different hardware, or re-write it in a totally different stack?  If you use a subdomain you can set-up the new stack anywhere and simply repoint the subdomain when you're ready.  And the website remains blissfully unaffected.

**Security**

Using a subdomain means the traffic can be processed differently at the networking level, meaning you can employ stuff like Web Application Firewalls (WAF) more effectively.  You can develop WAF policies that are more targeted to the needs of the situation for one system (e.g. the kiosk) without affecting the other.

**Who has system access**

Who is maintaining the website and the kiosk - is it the same company?  If so then accessing the same server appears fine - but if it's different companies (or even just different teams) having a degree of separation is generally wise.  Having a subdomain makes managing that easier as you have more ways of controlling them and keeping access separate.

**In summary**

In general terms, the more separated and segregated you can do things, the better. Because it tends to give you more options to respond to change.  There will always be a downside - such as greater complexity, or less convenience in the short-term.  Good architecture is all about laying the ground work to accommodate **likely** change in the longer-term.